# MongoDB Best-practice structure

Tags: mongodb, performance, data-structures, database

I wish to aggragate website statistics on 3 different levels:

- statistics per day
- statistics per campaign
- statistics per sources per campaign

On Mongo what is the recommended (performance wise) to store data that needs to be retrieved in the following matter:

```
{
    "somedate": {
        "324": {
            "count": 456,
            "subcampaigns": {
                "fff": {
                    "count": 45,
                    "sources": {
                        "s1": {
                            "count": 4
                        },
                        "s2": {
                            "count": 41
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the prediction is to have  ~1M per day and "sources" > 10K
would it be better to store in other collections or sub-jsons are good enough?
Is there a limit size?

Thx

Comment: There is no "right" way to do something like this. What should be done is determined by several factors. To name a few: what is your primary way of accessing the data? How are the instances scaled RAM wise? How many app servers are going to access the data? What is the ratio of reads and writes? How many indices are there? Do entries expire after a while or are they deleted manually? How often will the aggregations be run? These questions are only a few to be answered in order to determine the optimal data modeling and subsequently the setup of your databases. You need consultancy for that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 16MB limit when you want to retrieve the result without writing on disk. 
Allow disk usage on aggregation slows it  of course, but if you want to save the result to be able to request it after, writing the result in a collection is obviously the best choice.

By the way if you want to launch your request in back ground map/reduce might be a best solution, because it use way less memory and works quite transparently with it's yield system. You can even tack advantage of the incremental map reduce if you want to update your data without a huge cost (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-incremental-map-reduce/).